# Undefined local variable or method for module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have module `CurrencyExchange` with following methods

```
 CURRENCIES = %w(uah rub eur usd)

 def available_currencies
   CURRENCIES.join(' ').downcase.split.permutation(2)
 end
```

and when i want to use `available_currencies` with

`define_method`

```
 available_currencies.each do |(c1, c2)|
    define_method(:"#{c1}_to_#{c2}") do |cr| ... end end
```

i have got an error

```
undefined local variable or method `available_currencies'
 for CurrencyExchange:Module (NameError)
```

but when i use it like

```
     CURRENCIES.join(' ').downcase.split.permutation(2).each do |(c1, c2)|
  define_method(:"#{c1}_to_#{c2}") .... end end
```

it works fine

Why it happens?

Comment: There are some issues with this current logic. 
Please paste the `currency_exchange.rb` complete file here.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Don't forget to answer when you find an issue. +1 for `permutation` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to write `def self.available_currencies`

Answer (score 0):

You try to create other method in the class and Ruby searches in the loop for a class method `.available_currencies`.

You have to change your class method `.available_currencies` into a instance method `#available_currencies` or create the methods in your initializer.

**Method 1:**

```
class MyClass
  def self.available_currencies
    # Your logic...
  end

  # Your logic...
end
```

**Method 2:**

```
class MyClass
  def init
    available_currencies.each do |c|
      define_method(c) do
        # Whatever you want to do ...
      end
    end
  end

  def available_currencies
    # Your logic...
  end
end
```

I would recommend you the first way since you maybe want to use the currencies in classes. I would recommend you the second way, if you want for example different currencies for different instances.

Happy coding :)